# How do I connect an Ubuntu machine to a Windows VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn

On Windows 10 I'm able to connect to my company's VPN easily by going to VPN settings:

- "Add a VPN connection"
- Selecting "Windows (built in)" as the VPN provider
- Typing in the server name (remote.company.net)
- Leaving the VPN Type as "Automatic"
- Finally adding in my company username

On my Ubuntu machine, I go to Add VPN:

- Select PPTP (compatible with Microsoft and other PPTP VPN servers)
- Type in the gateway (remote.company.net)
- Add in my company username

And I'm unable to connect. Is there anything special that I'm missing that the built in Windows VPN is doing automatically? Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Edit: I'm running Ubuntu 20.04. I was able to determine that server I'm trying to connect to is actually using SSTP as it's protocol. After setting that up I'm receiving a `MS-CHAP authentication failed: E=649 No dialin permission`. Why would there be a dialin permission error if everything works alright with Windows? Suggestions?

Comment: How are you "unable to connect"? Is there an error message? Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: With windows you've told us it was windows 10, but you've provided no release version at all for Ubuntu. That maybe useful knowledge and a clue for us. Are you using a modern? supported? or deprecated release?  Why not tell us the release?

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply's! I looked at the logs and referred back to windows and determined that the server was working on an SSTP protocol and not PPTP. After setting up SSTP and trying to connect I'm receiving a new error - `MS-CHAP authentication failed: E=649 No dialin permission`. Why would I be receiving a no dialin permission error when everything works alright with windows? I'm on release 20.04.